# TextSwitcher Animation Customization

Tags: android, animation, textview

Can I use TextSwitcher animation with a TextView ? (I want to change it when Char changing)
Or
Can I change text size by code(like `TextView : txtView.setTextSize();`) and Change TextColor too.

Code's be simple

Answer (score 0):

After you placed your textswitcher view in the upper part of your code:

```
    TextSwitcher questionTextSwitcher = (TextSwitcher) findViewById(R.id.textSwitcher);
    questionTextSwitcher.setFactory(new MyTextSwitcherFactory());
```

here you can manipulate your textview:

```
        private class MyTextSwitcherFactory implements ViewSwitcher.ViewFactory {
           public View makeView() {
                 TextView textView = new TextView(CurrentClass.this);
                 textView.setGravity(Gravity);
                 textView.setTextSize(size);
                 textView.setTextColor(Color);
                }
            }
```